# VD: error VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND opening image file

Tags: virtualbox

I just changed my computer, but when i reopen the VM and try to restore the snapshot, i get this error

```
Could not open the medium 'C:\VM\Centos6.7.vdi'.
VD: error VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\VM\Centos6.7.vdi' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND).
```

the Centos6.7.vdi is now placed in D:\VM\, but now i can't find any ways to change it.

ps. i've reset the UUID by command, seems screwed up something.

when i open media manager, it is greyed out, how can i fix this problem, i want to restore the snapshots.